# pandas group dataframe based on value of other dataframe

Tags: pandas

This is my commission dataframe:

```
id  advertiser_id  system_commission contract_commission start_date                       end_date                      is_first is_last
0   1              1                 1.1000              2.1000 2017-10-01 15:26:00+00:00 2018-10-01 15:26:00+00:00      True    False
1   2              1                 1.1000              2.2000 2018-10-01 15:26:00+00:00 2018-12-01 15:26:00+00:00     False    False
2   3              1                 1.1000              2.3000 2018-12-01 15:26:00+00:00 2019-10-01 15:26:00+00:00     False    False
3   4              1                 1.1000              2.4000 2019-10-01 15:26:00+00:00 2020-10-01 15:26:00+00:00     False     True
```

I have a report dataframe which has 1000's of entries.

```
id  date                   
0   2017-10-01 15:26:00+00:00
1   2017-10-01 15:26:00+00:00
2   2018-11-01 15:26:00+00:00
3   2018-12-02 15:26:00+00:00
```

now I want to group report dataframe based on start_date and end_date of commission dataframe.
Means row 0 and 1 of report df will be under one group as they between in start_date and end_date of row 0 of commission df, same way row 2 of report df will be in one group alone as it comes in between start_date and end_date of row 1 of commission df.

I don't have much knowledge of pandas but this is how i created dataframe:

```
commission_df = pd.DataFrame(list(Commission.objects.all().values()))
```

I converted my django models to dataframe.

Comment: What code have to tried so far? Also please share the minimum example to create the dataframe.

Comment: @srishtigarg hi i have written at last, i didn't wrote it earlier because it may create complications for answerers as i converted djaango model into df.